# How to get imported data from excel in the shapefile properties?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I imported some data from excel (as csv) to ArcMap. The information from the "excel table" has been joined to my shapes and is shown at the attribute table of every shape/layer. (As you can see below).

[image]

However, when I export it to GIS online I see the information isn't there. With some research I found out the information is visible at the attribute tables, but it isn't at the fields in the shapefile properties.

[image]

Is there a way to add the 2006,2009,2010,Total fields from the attribute table to the shapefile properties?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that if you export the data(right click the layer in contents pane, data > export data as shapefile... (the shapefile with the joined table) then import that newly created shapefile  all the fields will be in your properties.

Comment: Just an additional note that you can go to the joined shapefile's properties in the Fields tab and toggle on/off the fields you would like before exporting the data.  Much nicer than manually deleting fields after the fact.

Comment: I think I tried that yesterday, it worked, but this way would be a lot of work for me (because of the high amount of shapefiles). Thought maybe there is an easier way to do it... I have also seen things with the dbf file, so maybe it is something with a database where I can change the attributes?

Comment: I changed the Fieldalias from every column and put the "0" columns to off. After the export, the Fieldaliases are again the same as the Fieldnames (so field3/4...). The "0" column on/off tip is working!